# How much voltage can one layer of a common black electrical tape block?

Tags: insulation

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_tape) just "Low voltage, phase B". The tape I bought has no specification about such property on the package. About how much voltage can one layer of such tape block? If one layer can block X volts, does using two layers block 2X volts?

[image]

Comment: I dont think you will ever find a spec about "a layer" of electrical tape, since when you use it you can stretch it, which would change the spec. The times I've seen it written was always something like "x mm of tape can withstand y kV"

Comment: Tape is easily penetrated by sharp corners, cut strands, metal filings etc.  for any safety-critical application it would be most unwise to rely on adhesive tape unless the conditions of its use are well controlled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UL 510](https://standards.globalspec.com/std/14207508/UL%20510) rating for "low voltage" applications specifies a 600 volt (!) dielectric withstand. You can reasonably assume any good quality vinyl tape will at least be able to withstand (household) mains voltage. If you buy cheap unrated clone tape of unknown material/construction, all bets are off. Good quality tape will have some kind of stated rating.

Comment: Ah. That is a lot higher than I expected. I was wondering if it could safely insulate a DC 12V PCB.

Comment: @DamnVegetables Oh yes, I can't fathom even a cheap fake knockoff product marketed as "electrical tape" not being able to handle well above 12 V. No worries!

Comment: At just 12 volts scotch tape would be enough--it takes a lot more than that to start having problems.

Comment: @Hearth Quite true, but scotch tape can give you ESD problems so I wouldn't ever advise using it on a PCB. Your point is well taken though.